# How to install node 5.4.1 using brew

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am trying the following `brew` statement on console, but required node version is not found

```
brew install node@5.4.1
```

Does anybody knows how to install node version 5.4.1 by using Homebrew? This version is mandatory when using SAP HAT framework and is no longer possible to use previously node versions.

Futher information about HAT may be found on the following link: https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide_hat/frameset.htm

Comment: Isn't this answered here already:
[http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207883](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/207883)

Comment: For managing node versions, `n` is much easier to use. https://github.com/tj/n

Answer (score 0):

You can’t install a specific version of Node with Homebrew if nobody wrote a formula (= package) for it. Homebrew doesn’t magically knows how to retrieve Node version 5.4.1 and how to build it.

You have to either install that version another way (e.g. using [n](https://github.com/tj/n)) or create your own Homebrew formula (see the [`node@6`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/node%406.rb) one).